# ember 'if' tag causes elements to dissapear

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a view template 'person' defined as:

```
....
{{input type="checkbox" checked=isEditing}}
<table><tbody>
    {{#if 'isEditing'}}
        <tr><td><strong>Id</strong></td>{{id}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>number</strong></td><td>{{repNumber}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>First Name</strong></td><td>{{firstName}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>Middle Name</strong></td><td>{{middleName}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>Last Name</strong></td><td>{{lastName}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>alias 1</strong></td><td>{{alias1}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>alias 2</strong></td><td>{{alias2}}</td></tr>
    {{else}}
        <tr><td><strong>Id</strong></td>{{id}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>number</strong></td><td>{{repNumber}}</td></tr>
        <tr><td><strong>First Name</strong></td><td>{{input type="text" value=firstName</td></tr>
        <!-- input counterparts etc -->
    {{/if}}
</tbody></table>
....
```

And a PersonController defined as such:

```
App.Editable = Em.Mixin.create({
    isEditing: false,
    actions: {
        edit: function() {
            this.toggleProperty('isEditing');
        }
    }
});

App.PersonController = Em.ObjectController.extend(SS7.Editable);
```

The route is defined like so:

```
App.Router.map(function(){
    ...
    this.resource('person', { path: '/person/:person_id'}, function(){});
});
```

Now every time I first toggle the `isEditing` value using the checkbox, all of my elements suddenly disappear off the screen. The Ember inspector shows that the viewTree is currently on the person route with the PersonController and the model contains the correct person. however i can now no longer see any of the two outputs (tr,tds) until i hard refresh the page.

Can anyone help to explain this behaviour. I'm unsure how this could be happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, these type of issues are hard to find, the thing is that you are missing a < td > and that makes your code fail, well, not fail because it doesn't throw any errors, but it fails when building the HTML, the error is in this part:

```
{{#if isEditing}}
    <tr><td><strong>Id</strong></td>{{id}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><strong>number</strong></td><td>{{repNumber}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><strong>First Name</strong></td><td>{{firstName}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><strong>Middle Name</strong></td><td>{{middleName}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><strong>Last Name</strong></td><td>{{lastName}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><strong>alias 1</strong></td><td>{{alias1}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><strong>alias 2</strong></td><td>{{alias2}}</td></tr>
{{else}}
```

check the first < tr >, you're missing a < td > before {{id}}, it should be like this:

```
{{#if isEditing}}
    <tr><td><strong>Id</strong></td><td>{{id}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><strong>number</strong></td><td>{{repNumber}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><strong>First Name</strong></td><td>{{firstName}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><strong>Middle Name</strong></td><td>{{middleName}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><strong>Last Name</strong></td><td>{{lastName}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><strong>alias 1</strong></td><td>{{alias1}}</td></tr>
    <tr><td><strong>alias 2</strong></td><td>{{alias2}}</td></tr>
{{else}}
```

Comment: Yeah, That was the issue alright, I was trying to sift through it before, but I suppose my ultra one-line nesting was getting the better of me. Thanks!